# How to change parts of parameters' device type of a module in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I define a `net` and two parameters are on CPU, I try to move those two parameters to GPU. However, when I print the device, I find that those two are not moved to GPU.
How to change the model parameter device?

```
for p in net.parameters():
    if p.device == torch.device('cpu'):
        p = p.to('cuda')


for p in net.parameters():
    if p.device == torch.device('cpu'):
        print(p.device)
```

Output:

```
cpu
cpu
```

Comment: but you can do `net.cuda()` directly

Comment: @Prajot Kuvalekar I want to place different parameters on different devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dealing with parameters. Unlike a `Module`, you have to attribute them back to the original variable if you want to replace them. Additionally, you'll want to change the `.data` of a given parameter, otherwise it won't work because the `.to(...)` actually generates a copy.

```py
for p in net.parameters():
    if p.device == torch.device('cpu'):
        p.data = p.to('cuda')
```

Note that if any of these parameters have `.grad`, they will not be moved to the GPU. Take a look [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/80cab10534e1a9ee6d2493113f169a2570979651/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L551-L574) at how parameters are usually moved. As you'll see, you'll have to do the same for the gradients:

```py
for p in net.parameters():
    if p.device == torch.device('cpu'):
        p.data = p.to('cuda')
        if p.grad is not None:
            p.grad.data = p.grad.to('cuda')
```

Comment: Those two parameters are trainable variables, they have `.grad`. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @skytree You have to move them as well (see edit). But I think that it is very unlikely that they'll have `.grad` at the moment you're moving them.